# Iron Router's layouts, dynamic templates and static templates in Meteor

Tags: node.js, templates, meteor, frontend, iron-router

I'm discovering Meteor and I have a little question about utilisation cases. Currently, I know 3 kinds of templates :

- "static" templates
- dynamic templates
- layouts (provides by Iron Router)

I'm experiencing Meteor with a little web-app and I don't really know which one I have to use.

I know that I should use *dynamic templates* when I need to change a template inside an other.

About *layouts*, the official doc says `Layouts allow you to reuse a common look and feel in multiple pages in your application so you don't have to duplicate the html and logic on every single page template.`

#### My case

I have a left sidebar navigation (fixed) and my content is on the right. The question is pretty simple : which feature should I use ?

#### Ideas

I can create a template (`main.html`) and insert into it a dynamic template. I would be able to refresh the dynamic template depending on the page/content I have to show.

```
<template name="main">
    <nav>
        <!-- my sidebar -->
    </nav>

    <main>
        <!-- the content -->
        {{> Template.dynamic template=template data=data}}
    </main>
</template>
```

I can also use the layout system provided by Iron Router

```
<template name="main">
    <nav>
        <!-- my sidebar -->
    </nav>

    <main>
        <!-- the content -->
        {{> yield}}
    </main>
</template>
```

Or simply, I can create one template per page and include in each one the `nav` template to display the sidebar.
But it seems really bad.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: In my experience, the layout approach has been appropriate for all of my applications.  It seems what you want to do with the sidebar on each page would be a good candidate for a layout

Comment: I would recommend this as well. Wrap the sidebar into the layout template and use {{>yield}} for the parts that change.

Comment: The use cases for dynamic templates are much less common than for using `{{>yield}}` with a router (either iron-router or flow-router). For example you might use them if you want to inherit event handlers from a template in several sub-templates. Keep your code DRY and avoid creating a master layout for every route!

Comment: Thanks for all you answers :) !